# How to display GNUPLOT keys in multiple lines

Tags: gnuplot, legend

How can I please display gnuplot titles in multiple lines or even in columns. Indeed I have 8 titles and I juste used this :

```
set key below
```

So each one is displayed in a seperate line. So the figure becomes congested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
set terminal postscript enhanced color
set output 'plot.eps'

set key below
plot sin(x) title "{/Arial=8 LongFunctionKeyName}", \
 sin(2*x) title "{/Arial=8 LongFunctionKeyName}", \
 sin(3*x) title "{/Arial=8 LongFunctionKeyName}", \
 sin(4*x) title "{/Arial=8 LongFunctionKeyName}", \
 sin(5*x) title "{/Arial=8 LongFunctionKeyName}", \
 sin(6*x) title "{/Arial=8 LongFunctionKeyName}", \
 sin(7*x) title "{/Arial=8 LongFunctionKeyName}", \
 sin(8*x) title "{/Arial=8 LongFunctionKeyName}", \
 sin(9*x) title "{/Arial=8 LongFunctionKeyName}", \
 sin(10*x) title "{/Arial=8 LongFunctionKeyName}", \
 sin(11*x) title "{/Arial=8 LongFunctionKeyName}", \
 sin(12*x) title "{/Arial=8 LongFunctionKeyName}", \
 sin(13*x) title "{/Arial=8 LongFunctionKeyName}"
```

This is the output in gnuplot 4.6:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
By using

    set key below

I get the keys outside the figure and in multiple lines.But since I have several keys their display the height of the figure becomes reduced. Also my keys are a little long so even displaying them on the left margin will reduce the figure's width.  
Then I would like to display them in several columns for example or reduce their font size while displaying them below the figure.